# How can SO detect that user has two accounts?

Tags: discussion, users, accounts, duplicate-accounts

It seems that SO can detect user with two accounts by their IP. But are there any other ways to detect it?

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways to detect that:

- Comparing email address,
- Comparing names,
- Comparing IP addresses,
- Black magic,
- Gut feelings of community members,
- Being Jon Skeet,
- Asking Google,
- Probably some machine learning.

Which methods SE use aren't public knowledge, and probably shouldn't be, considering knowing the system makes it too easy to abuse the system.

Comment: Well, I can have two different email addresses and names. It's not so easy to expose same accounts.

Comment: Well, *I* can have *three*.

Comment: I think 4 is the absolute limit with current technology levels.

Comment: And if you're just random like me, you have more than five email addresses.

Comment: @ivarni I can have 1000.

Comment: @VerNick That would be so hard to manage it would not be worth the effort of creating them all.

Comment: _Peasants_. I have __infinite__ email addresses. `<accountname>+<random>@gmail.com`.

Comment: And on that bombshell, I think it's time to end.

Comment: @Cerbrus And what the passwords will be? <Cerbus>+<random>+123454321?

Comment: Actually, I have __2*infinite__ email addresses. I have a catch-all on my own domain :D

Comment: @VerNick Those are not actual accounts. Cerbrus is making a joke about a well known Gmail feature. No separate passwords are needed.

Comment: Also, don't be silly, my gmail account name isn't the same as my SO one.

Comment: @yivi I don't know about that feature, can you give me a link?

Comment: @VerNick: here: https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Comment: @yivi I'm not that smart, you know.

Comment: It's from the RFC 5233. Many mail provider implment it not only gmail. It's call the "plus addressing". It's for aliasing

Comment: I think that we got outta the main theme of question.

Comment: Well, this comments chain was a fun ride.

Comment: It's probably a lot less sophisticated then you all think it is.

Comment: I'm surprised that IP Addresses were not mentioned on this list.

Comment: Actually, there is a length limitation on mail addresses, so it's finite, though lots. There's a finite amount of possible email addresses with the current specification.

Comment: One item to add to the list: gut feelings of community members. If you're here long enough, you learn to spot things that are out of the ordinary. For example, [my warning here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375505/post-every-90-minutes-error#comment639441_375505) came as the result of removing an account that was asking the same questions, with the same style, and community members complaining about that. The community is still a pretty good early warning system, on top of all the other tools we have for finding these.